# Normalizing ARIMA(0,2,q) generator

Tags: time-series, arima, simulation, unit-root

I'm doing simulations of an ARIMA(0,d,q) process, and confused about the scaling when d=1 vs d=2.  Using a series of random terms $e_t \sim N(0,1)$:

I generate $Y_{d1}$ ~ ARIMA(0,1,0) as $y_t = y_{t-1} + e_t$ and get series that typically range between (-5, 5) for t < 100.  Here is a typical example:
[image: ARIMA(0,1,0) generated from 200 N(0,1) samples]

I generate $Y_{d2}$ ~ ARIMA(0,2,0) as $y_t = 2 y_{t-1} - y_{t-2} + e_t$ and get series that range well beyond (-500, 500) for t < 100.  The following is the $Y_{d2}$ generated using the exact same random numbers used to generate the sample $Y_{d1}$ charted above.
[image: ARIMA(0,2,0) generated from the same samples as the ARIMA(0,1,0) series above]

I want $Y_{d2}$ to have a range similar to that of $Y_{d1}$.  Is there a correct way to generate series $Y_{d2}$ so that they are scaled to a similar magnitude?

(I suspect that there is a normalization that should be applied to the second-difference generator ... and that it might properly be on the time axis, and/or in the variance parameter of the $e_t$ terms.)

Comment: Hi: you can probably just change the initial conditions so that the series have the same magnitude. You didn't say what you were using for the initial conditions but those are going to heavily influence the range of any series that you generate. This isn't an answer but I suggest you play with the initial conditions to get series in the same range.

Comment: @mlofton Perhaps naively, I am setting the first two values of y = 0.  So the d=2 process tends to pick a direction and just run in it.  Am I thinking about initial values incorrectly?

Comment: Is $Y_{d2}$ even stationary?  Its first difference is a random walk.

Comment: @whuber No, neither of the series are stationary, and yes $Y_{d1}$ is a random walk.  The motive here is that I'm trying to generate simulated data that "look" like real data sets that tests show are integrated order 1 and order 2.  Series simulated as shown for $Y_{d1}$ do look like the real data.  But series simulated as shown for $Y_{d2}$ do not.  ("Range over 100 points starting at y=0" is a coarse indicator of whether the data look similar.)

Comment: Since the series is not stationary, and is an integrated random walk, we *expect* it to wander all over.  There's no inherent meaning to the magnitudes of the values it attains.  Recall that even the tiniest deviations early on in such a series get magnified exponentially as time goes on.  It makes sense to normalize a stationary series, because it has a limiting variance, but you can't do that with random walks.

Comment: @whuber Assuming it's possible, I want to scale the d=2 series so that it "looks" something like the d=1 series.  Without knowing what (if any) measures typically characterize random walks, here are some off the top of my head: Within 100 iterations its magnitude doesn't exceed +/-5, and its signal/noise doesn't exceed 2, in more than 20% of simulations.  I can sort of kludge it to do this by sticking scalars in various places, but I feel like I must be missing something formal.

Comment: @feetwet: As whuber said, since these series are both non-stationary, there's no real way of "knowing' where they will go. But, if you wanted to get them roughly in the same range, you could initialize the first series with $0$ and then just play around with the initial condition of the second series so that it roughly has the same range. So, for some initialization of the second series, you might be able to get them to be in the same range. The problem with this approach is that you've  taken the randomness out of the process because the only thing they both depend on is the initial value.

Comment: @feetwet: Just to finish my comment above, the only way to get the two series to be different each time is to have the initial value of each series be randomly generated and, if the two initial values are randomly generated, then you won't be able to insure that they are in the same range. So, you kind of have a catch-22. At the same time, I'm not clear on what you gain by having them be in the same range. If you explain that, maybe it will generate some more ideas.

Comment: @mlofton I just added examples to the question.  I also don't understand the significance of the initial values or initial conditions: I'm starting every generated series at 0, and I'm running them for a few hundred iterations before generating a new sample starting at 0.

Comment: Based on what chris wrote below, I just realized that my previous comment about getting the same series each time is wrong since you still have the error term $\epsilon_t$ in both cases. So, you will get a different series each time, even if you set the initial value to the same things each time. My mistake there and thanks to chris for opening my eyes on that one. Apologies for contributed confusion and read what chris wrote because hopefully that will provide some enlightenment. I'm still not clear on why you need them to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ARIMA process isn't defined only by its transition distribution (or, equivalently, by the recurrence you show): you must specify an initial distribution. This can be less important when the process is stationary or there is a unique long-run distribution to which it tends (regardless of the initial distribution), but that doesn't apply here. You mention in a comment that you want it to start from the degenerate distribution $Y_0 = Y_{-1} = 0$, so let's go with that.

You can compute the distribution of an $\text{ARIMA}(0,d,0)$ process at a fixed instant exactly. For a normal $\text{ARIMA}(0,1,0)$ starting at $Y_0=0$, we have that:

$$Y_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, t\sigma^2)$$

And for a normal $\text{ARIMA}(0,2,0)$ starting at $Y_0 = Y_{-1} = 0$, we have:

$$Y_t \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{t(t+1)(2t+1)}{6}\sigma^2\right)$$

As you can see, the variance for $d=1$ is $\mathcal{O}(t)$, while for $d=2$ it is $\mathcal{O}(t^3)$. The variance of a twice integrated process grows much faster than for a random walk. Therefore, there can't be a *constant* rescaling that will match the variance of a $d=2$ process with that of a $d=1$ process at *every* point in time.

If $t$ is bounded (you seem to consider only $t \leq 100$), then you could always rescale so that the maximum variances match (i.e. so that the variance at $t=100$ is the same). However, this will make the variance of the $d=2$ process very very small for smaller $t$. It's not completely clear to me what you're trying to do or whether this would be acceptable for that.